# Passing a context of a fragment to a class and display an alert dialog

Tags: android, fragment

I am currently working on an android project and I am having a problem with contexts and AlertDialogs.

I have a class which extends a Fragment and it creates an instance of a standard Java class called `Common` which has the context passed to it from the Fragment. In the `Common` class I have some code to display an alert dialog and return a boolean based on what the user clicked.

With a standard class that extends an Activity I can create the instance of the Common class using the following:

```
Common common = new Common(this);
```

Then I can call my show alert dialog function within this class by using the following code.

```
common.showYesNoDialog("This is my message", false);
```

The code above works fine, for a standard `Activity` class. My problem is this.

In my Class that Extends Fragment I can't pass `this` to the common class so I instead have to use the following code:

```
Common common = new Common(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
```

and I use the following code as normal:

```
common.showYesNoDialog("This is my message", false);
```

When I call the function above I get the following error:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application.
```

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: If the common constructor works with `this` where `this` is an `Activity` instance, why are you then making a Common with `getApplicationContext()`? Why not just use `getActivity()`?

Comment: have you tried this `Common common = new Common(Your_Current_Activity.this);`

Comment: @A--C thanks I was thinking for some reason I needed to say ``getApplicationContext`` as I am passing a context. But your right with just using getActivity. Could you make it an answer and I'll accept it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use `getActivity()` instead of `getActivity().getApplicationContext()` since getActivity() returns an Activity which is a subclass of Context.